# How the position of adverb affect the meaning of a sentence

Tags: adverb-placement

> 1)The country girl **cast down her eyes shyly**;
>
> 2)The country girl **shyly cast down her eyes**.

Are the two sentence both correct and equivalent in meaning?

Comment: Do you see some difference?

Comment: I cannot feel the difference in meaning, aside from the difference in postion.

Comment: If the intended meaning is the same, then either one would be OK. Adverbs can often be placed at more than one location in a sentence, which may somewhat affect the meaning. All other things being equal, I would recommend adverb placement close to the word it modifies, as in example 2.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is a matter of emphasis.

In #1, the sentence uses the standard order:
subject (The country girl), verb (cast down), direct object (her eyes), indirect object (not present), and adverbial phrases (shyly).

In #2, the adverbial phrase has been promoted to a position just before the verb it modifies. The meaning of the sentence has not changed, but the significance of the promoted word has been increased.